# msbuild and subversion

Tags: svn, msbuild

Im trying to use msbuild to get the latest version of my code from my subversion repository. I'm trying to use the [msbuild community tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/) and in particluar the svn tasks to pull down the latest version of my code. I'm unsure which task(s) I need to use to achieve this (SvnClient, SvnUpdate)

Currently my msbuild target looks like this

```
<Target Name="GetLatestFromSVN">
 <SvnClient
   RepositoryPath="https://mySvnRepositorytrunk/src/current"
   ToolPath="C:\Program Files\Subversion\bin"
   Username="Username"
   Password="password"
   LocalPath="$(BuildRootPath)\src">
 </SvnClient>
</Target>
```

Im unsure what the Command parameter should be or if I should be using the SvnClient task at all. Can anyone help?

Comment: May I ask what you're trying to do? Do you know about "Continuous Integration" servers, and their purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you need SvnUpdate to ensure you always get the latest changes of your code before building.

Comment: So thats just SvnUpdate and all the remaining attributes remain same? 
Can you link me to the official documentation

Comment: want to know the SVN Update in terms of MSBuild Extension Pack like the example he cites above, Tags and Attributes. Are they the same as SvnClient?

Comment: its been a few years... try this for a pointer to help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645253/msbuild-and-svn-update google might be able to help you more.

Comment: Thanks gbjbaanb it shows an example of svn commit but good reference.
I figured out how to do it and it just invokes the command line SVN commands nothing different wrt to replacement with the Attributes used in MSBuild
refs:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118102/how-do-i-import-the-msbuildcommunitytasks-project-from-another-msbuild-project-w

Answer (score 1):

To pull down the latest for the first time its best to use SvnCheckout