# MSBuild Extension Pack simple tutorial

Tags: msbuild

I am looking for a very simple example that shows what exactly is and how to use the MSBuild Extension Pack: http://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/ I just cannot find anything for a real beginner. Thank you.

Comment: If you understand MSBuild, then using tasks from the EP shouldn't be an issue. Are you looking for basic MSBuild information?

Comment: I do understand MSBuild but I am looking for a simple example on how to use the Extension Pack. I know I need it but I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: import the tasks and use it. FWIW, SO is a much better resource when your questions are specific to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Ok, but use it how? In code, in a script, in an XML file?

Comment: Imported as a task and used by a target in a msbuild file. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k6kkbsd.aspx - Are you using TFS?

Comment: Thank you! This is good enough indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go through these Links,
They would be very useful, I figured out how to use MSBuildCommunityTasks through them,

[How do I import the msbuildcommunitytasks project from another msbuild project with a relative file path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118102/how-do-i-import-the-msbuildcommunitytasks-project-from-another-msbuild-project-w)

[Msbuild and SVN update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645253/msbuild-and-svn-update)

Also,
Example

```
<SvnUpdate 
    Username="$(CommitUser)" 
    Password="$(CommitPassword)" 
    LocalPath="$(ProjectDir)">
</SvnUpdate>
```

Its just what you use on the Command Line.